# Show only IF not Google bot

Tags: php, functions, google

I have some code (ad banners etc.) that I would like to not show to Google. Is it possible to create a conditional statement that will disable a function or template part, if the site is requested by Google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really a WordPress specific question. However, I recently wrote a function for this (and blocking other user agents). Perhaps you could use it, or some of it?:

```
function is_a_bot(){

    $is_bot = false;

    $user_agents = array( 'GTmetrix', 'Googlebot', 'Bingbot', 'BingPreview', 'msnbot', 'slurp', 'Ask Jeeves/Teoma', 'Baidu', 'DuckDuckBot', 'AOLBuild' );

    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    foreach ( $user_agents as $agent ){
        if ( strpos( $user_agent, $agent) ){
            $is_bot = true;
        }
    }

    return $is_bot;

}
```

Simply add/remove the bots that you want/don't want from the array `$user_agents` and use in the following way:

```
if ( ! is_a_bot() ){
    // Do something if it's not a bot (eg. display ad code, template part or run your function here...)
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Have you tested it - is there a way to test it?

Comment: You could test it quite easily with GTMetrix - simply run a GTMetrix speed test while including a load of Javascript or unoptimised images, then run the same test with the assets loaded conditionally within the `is_a_bot()` function. As long as the user-agent names are correct, it will work for all other user agents.

Comment: Great solution, add 'Chrome-Lighthouse', 'Google PageSpeed Insights' for Google Speed Insights robots.